# Create or Delete Html Table Rows

Tags: jquery, html

I need to make one thing 1)Create or Delete Rows. 
**Errors Found** the genereted rows don't execute the buttons actions add or delete (not coded), I'm using the same attributes used in the original buttons.I dont know why is this happening, the append method dont clone the rows values ?who other do it?

```
  <table class="tabla_uno table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >#</th>
        <th >First Name</th>
        <th >Last Name</th>
        <th >Username</th>
        <th ></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td class="controls">
          <button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
          <button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td class="controls">
          <button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
          <button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  <hr>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
// ADD
  $(document).on("click", ".boton_mas",function()
  {
    var datos = $(".tabla_uno tbody tr:first").clone();
    $("#product").append($(this).html());
    var insertHere = $(this).closest("tr");
    datos.insertAfter(insertHere);
  })

  // REMOVE
  $(document).on("click", '.boton_menos', function() 
  {
    var rowCount = $('.tabla_uno tbody tr').length;
    var MinRwows = 1;        
    if (rowCount === MinRwows)
    {
      alert("Minimo alcanzado, no puedes borrar mas filas");          
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  })
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you seem to be looking for. You'll want to populate the new rows differently, of course, but it'll get you closer.

Note that I had to add the event listener to the document itself, rather than listening for the selector directly. This is because of the dynamically created elements -- the event listeners defined before they're created don't catch them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  /*****
   * This function will add a row to the given table directly
   *   after the row containing the clicked plus button. It will
   *   clone the first table row each time, then empty it of all
   *   data, then insert it into the given location.
   *****/
  $(document).on("click", '.boton_mas', function() {
    // Find the first table body row, and clone it.
    var datos = $(".tabla_uno tbody tr:first").clone();

    // Replace the row number with the newly obtained number.
    datos.find("th").empty();

    // Stick dummy content into the clone's td's.
    datos.find("td").not(".controls").each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).index());
    });

    // Locate the row that was clicked. We'll add right after this.
    var insertHere = $(this).closest("tr");

    // And stick the new row in.
    datos.insertAfter(insertHere);
    
    // Hide the control buttons...
    datos.find(".boton_mas, .boton_menos").hide();
    
    // Now, we need to re-index all the rows headers:
    $(".tabla_uno tbody th").each(function(){
      // get the index of the row itself, increment it by one
      //   as indices are zero-based, and change the th text.
      $(this).text(parseInt($(this).closest("tr").index()) +1);
    })
  }) // end .on("click", ".boton_mas")

  /****
   * This function will remove rows when the minus button has
   *  been clicked. It will only run when there are more than 
   *  one row, otherwise, it will do nothing.
   ****/
  $(document).on("click", '.boton_menos', function() {
    // This if statement will force a minimum of one row.
    if($(".tabla_uno tbody tr").length > 1){
      // Simply remove the ancestor TR containing this 
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    
    }
  }) // end .on("click", ".boton_menos")
  
  // Utility functions to hide and show the add/remove buttons.
  //  Note that these expect that the css was used to hide them.
  $(document).on("mouseenter",".tabla_uno tbody tr", function(){
    // Row is hovered, show the buttons.
    $(this).find(".boton_mas, .boton_menos").show();
  }).on("mouseleave", ".tabla_uno tbody tr", function(){
    // Row is no longer hovered, hide them again!
    $(this).find(".boton_mas, .boton_menos").hide();
  });
})
```

```css
.boton_mas, .boton_menos {
  display: none;
}

tr {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabla_uno table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td class="controls">
        <button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
        <button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td class="controls">
        <button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
        <button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Larry the Bird</td>
      <td> Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td class="controls">
        <button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
        <button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, to make the insert work as you'd like (where the new row is added immediately following the clicked row), simply find the TR that contains the clicked element and use `datos.insertAfter(insertHere);` as you can see in the above code.

So there were two more changes you wanted made, to fit your case. Both pretty trivial, both pretty reasonable. If you look at the end of the '.boton_mas' function, you'll see an .each() loop that reindexes all rows when a row is added. You're absolutely right in your comment, we don't need to sum rows, simply need to reindex the entire thing. Easily done, check the loop.

The other change, to force one or more rows (so NOT allowing the last remaining row to be deleted) is simply done by adding the if statement, as I did in the '.boton-menos' function. That checks first to see if there is more than one row remaining and, if there is, doing the processing of removing the clicked row. Otherwise, the if is bypassed and the row is untouched.

Also, added the third functionality you were looking for, missed the comment regarding hiding/showing the add/remove buttons unless the row was being hovered. You'll see them at the end of the code block, commented as usual.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello snowmonkey, your code work, but i need to add the row next to the button i pushed(lets say i press 1 - Mark), the rows must to be next to it. And the buttons has to be hide when the mouse is not on the rows

Comment: @fsnfusion, Try it now. I've made the change to handle this.

Comment: Good Morning Snowmonkey. Thats it !... The only thing it need is the buttons show only when the mouse hover the td, can i vote for you after that or now?

Comment: Another thing i saw in your code is, we can remove all rows, thats not right, we need to make a limit, min 1 row

Comment: another thing i saw, theres no need to sum the rows, its only add or remove one at the desired position

Comment: You're right, @fsnfusion -- the rows don't need to be summed. I've made the three changes you've asked for: the add/remove only show on hover, the last remaining row can't be deleted and the rows are all re-indexed when a new row is added, thus removing the need for the sum. Hope this was what you're looking for. For the record, much more of writing your code for you, I may be asking for a job! ;)

Comment: Hello Snowmonkey, fantastic work !. Im doing this right now. Im charging the table with json data (done). If i create another row, how can i make a database insert with all the new data? any ideas?

Comment: So you want, in addition to the add/remove buttons, a save button? Currently, you have no mechanism for storing row data. I'm assuming when you create a row, you're populating it with form fields, and somehow you want to pass that form data via AJAX?

Comment: I make a each in jquery to get the tds, of course i dont want the td of the buttons

Comment: thats right, see my updated code, i want to pass the td data via ajax to php

Comment: We're getting beyond the scope of the original question. Not evading the question, but it would appear the project is advancing to a later phase. It is a pretty complex question, and one you may want to pose as a new question. Basically, you're going to need to gather your form data, and then post that to your php receiver. Then, on success, toggle the inputs to plain text (i assume).

Comment: Yes. It's basically other function. That is to save the td data to a database.

Comment: I think if we do it in this question. More people can use the code in this post and don't lose time to search in others question. This project is common use for everyone I think

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, once again been away. I'm actually building this into a sizeable tutorial thing, as there are a lot of moving pieces here that seem to need fixing: templating, encapsulation, design patterns. It's a complex subject, but done right it should be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".tabla_uno").on('click','.boton_mas',function()
 {      
          let TR=$("<tr/>");          
          let TD1=$("<td/>",{text:'1'});
          let TD2=$("<td/>",{text:'2'});
          let TD3=$("<td/>",{text:'3'});
          let TD4=$("<td/>",{text:'4'});
          let TDBTN=$("<td/>");
          let BTN_mas=$("<button/>",{class:'boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm',text:'+'});
          let BTN_menos=$("<button/>",{class:'boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm',text:'-'});
          TR.append(TD1);
          TR.append(TD2);
          TR.append(TD3);
          TR.append(TD4);
          TDBTN.append(BTN_mas);
          TDBTN.append(BTN_menos);
          TR.append(TDBTN);
   $(".tabla_uno tbody").append(TR);
 });
     $(".tabla_uno").on('click','.boton_menos',function()
      {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();   
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabla_uno table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>
<button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
<button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th >2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>
<button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
<button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>       
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th >3</th>
      <td>Larry the Bird</td>
      <td> Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>
<button class='boton_mas btn btn-success btn-sm'>+</button>
<button class='boton_menos btn btn-danger btn-sm'>-</button>       
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: seems okay.  But you need to include jQuery library in your html.

Comment: Try removing the rows you've just added -- the event listener is not bound to them.

Comment: Do not you want to use jQuery?

Comment: There you go. The `$(document).on(...)` does listen to dynamic events. Looks good.

Comment: Now the only thing i don't care for about this, and the original, is that the row being created is hard-coded in. By cloning one of the existing rows, and simply replacing all the appropriate content, my controls don't run the risk of breaking.

Comment: hello farhad, your code work, but i need to add the row next to the button i pushed(lets say i press 1 - Mark), the rows must to be next to it. And the buttons has to be hide when the mouse is not on the rows

Comment: @Snowmonkey -Thank you for the description. Can be simply generated if I know what is needed. This is an example

Comment: @FarhadBagherlo -- not doubting that you can, but in the OP's description he says that datos is an exact clone of an existing row. Thus, I simply clone an existing row. Neither approach is 'right', neither is 'better'. Yours works great, and I like it!